# Retrieving URL from jQuery .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, load, location

I would like to retrieve the URL (full path) of page2.html in the following setting:

```
page1.html
----------
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#content").load("page2.html");
    }
</script>
<div id='content'>
    <!-- this is where page2.html will be placed -->
</div>
----------

page2.html
----------
<script>alert(location.pathname)</script> //this should return the full path of page2.html, but now it returns page1.html
This is a line of content that will be loaded in page1.html
----------
```

My problem is that whenever I use url retrievers like document.URL, window.location or location.pathname it returns the full pathname of page1.html. This is probably because page2.html is loaded within page1.html, even though I do request the URL in page2.html.

Anyone has a solution for this or is this inevitable while using the .load() functionality?

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Well, I need to go back certain pages. And with .load() you cannot, as far as I'm concerned, go back. Since you are always on page1.html. So for example if i loaded page2.html in the content div, I should still be able to easily go back and replace the content with that from page1.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to execute some JavaScript to detect the path after the page is loaded, why not just use a callback to display the value of the path you already have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var path = "page2.html"
    $("#content").load(path, function() {
       alert(path);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You would either need to populate the URL in a hidden div or something on page2.html, probably via some server side technology, or you will need to construct the full path for page2.html yourself, given you already know the path to page1.html and page2.html is relative to it.

Comment: It does not appear that even if you used the complete callback for `load()` that you can get the full URL of the request.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript is executed after the load has occured therefore alerting page1 is correct behaviour. The only way I can see around that is storing the location manually in a javascript `var` on page 2.

Answer (score 0):

your `<script>alert(location.pathname)</script>` will not give you `page2.html` because you are just loading the contents of page2.html not the page. I mean if you load pag2.html in a iframe then you will get `page2.html`. Right now the contents is on page1.html so it will alert you page1.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do this with the help of Javascript. **Using load, you are not rendering the page but fetching the content.**

The use of `.load` is actually getting the data from the URL to the element. It uses AJAX call to fetch the data and dump it on the "#content" element and then your code is executed.

At this point of time, the URL reads page1.html and not page2.html.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the data loaded dynamically is inserted into the current page. If you really need to have the correct URL every time, use an iframe:

```
<iframe src="page2.html" style="width:100%;height:300px" id="page2_frame">Error</iframe>
```

However, if you use this method, the data in the iframe will only be 300 pixels high and a scroll bar will be shown if the content is longer. 
To access the content of the iframe, use `$("#page2_frame")[0].contentWindow`, which will return the window object for the iframe.

Ad@m

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you want to get can be achieved using `iframe` instead of a `div`.